# Jquery passing ID from <img> to function

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to pass the id in the function. no idea how to do it... :/

```
    $(function Myfunction(this) {
        $(this.id).udraggable({
            grid: [ 15, 15 ]
        });
    });


<img onclick="Myfunction(this)" src="files/pic/Website.png" id="Website">
```

Comment: try use `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 2):

1) pass this.id

```
<img onclick="Myfunction(this.id)" src="files/pic/Website.png" id="Website">
```

2) acess id in function

```
function Myfunction(id) {
  $("#"+id).udraggable({
      grid: [ 15, 15 ]
  });
}
```

Comment: the way of defining function is not correct, you will see error in console like: SyntaxError: missing formal parameter

Comment: yes, thats the only problem with OP's code. Everything else is fine.