# Javascript - img onlick() function passing arguments error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to pass arguments to  onclick handler. **The table rows are constructed dynamically in a loop** and each row contains a  tag with **different args**. Suppose there are two rows, and when clicking the first img, the argument is always the argument corresponding to the second(last) row.

JS code

```
for(...){
    
   id = get_id();  // every row's id is different
   img = '<img src="/img/icon-view.png" height="20" width="20" style="cursor:pointer" 
   onclick="view_detail(id)">'

   row = ('<tr> ' + '<td>' + img + '</td>' + '</tr>')

   $("#table_1").append(row)
}

function view_detail(id){
    ...
    // the first row's id is always the second id's row
}
```

Comment:
[Jquery passing ID from <img> to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562841/jquery-passing-id-from-img-to-function) gives a solution, but the trick here is id is a variable.

```
<img onclick="Myfunction(this.id)" src="files/pic/Website.png" id="Website">
```

Finally I found a workaround which is very simple - create img element and converts to string, and then put the string in row tag.

Sample code:

```
var img = document.createElement("img")
img.setAttribute("id","local_variable")
img.setAttribute("onclick","view_detail(this.id)")

var img_str = img.outerHTML(img)

row = '<tr>' + '<td>' + img_str + '</td>' + '</tr>'
```

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Delete the `onclick` attribute, delete `id = get_id();`. Instead, put `.on("click", "img", ((id) => () => view_detail(id))(get_id()))` after `$("#table_1").append(row)`.

Comment: I think you're just missing a `)` character at the end of the line where you define `row`.

Comment: @user4642212 This isn't a duplicate of that question, there's no closure here.

Comment: The JavaScript in `onclick` attributes is always executed in the global scope.

Comment: @user4642212: How is that a duplicate? There's no function in the loop.

Comment: @slappy Yes, I admit that it’s technically not the same scenario, but the problem is very similar: `id` gets assigned and reassigned in the loop (globally, in this case), and the function `view_detail` is called much later after the loop finished, so the value of `id` already corresponds to the last row, as described in the question.

Comment: @user4642212 But the solutions are very different. You can't fix this with a proper closure.

Comment: @user4642212: They're trying to use `id` in the loop (in a string), so it doesn't really matter that it's declared outside. They just don't know how to concatenate it. Even if they want the variable itself, I wouldn't create two functions on every iteration, invoking one, and keeping the scope alive of the other. There are much lower overhead solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use string to build DOM, but use `document.createElement()` instead. Then you can get instance of each target, add any event listeners, you can also pass those instances as arguments to other function as you want.

Here is a sample snippet you can try (I used button instead of img).

```js
const tbody = document.querySelector('table tbody')
const btnAddRow = document.querySelector('button#btn-add-row')

btnAddRow.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const row = document.createElement('tr')
  const col = document.createElement('td')
  const content = document.createElement('button')
  
  content.innerHTML = `Row ${tbody.childNodes.length}`
  
  content.addEventListener('click', e => {
    alert(`${content.innerHTML} clicked!`)
  })
   
  col.append(content)
  row.append(col)
  tbody.append(row)
})
```

```html
<button id="btn-add-row">Add row</button>
<hr>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another advantage is, your code becomes more readable and modern.

Answer (score 0):

Code in `onXXX` attributes is executed in the global scope, so it can't use captured local variables in a closure.

Nurul Huda's answer is ideal. But a simple fix to your code is to substitute the actual value of `id` rather than referencing the variable.

```
   id = get_id();  // every row's id is different
   img = `<img src="/img/icon-view.png" height="20" width="20" style="cursor:pointer" 
               onclick="view_detail(${id})">`
```

Comment: Thanks, but the browser reports an error "Unexpected token '{'. Expected ')' to end an argument list."

Comment: Are you sure you changed the quotes to backticks to create the template literal?